# changing theme folder name breaks menus - twentyeleven

Tags: menus

I needed to change the twentyeleven theme folder name, so I activated the default theme, changed the twentyeleven folder name to X, then reactivated it. Everything worked except the menus were all in the wrong places. I figured out they needed to be redefined in Menus>Theme Locations. But now, there's an extra sitemap listing in the footer.. I didn't put it there and can't figure out how to get rid of it. It's listing out the sitemap in ul tags, twice. Any suggesions?

Comment: A URL would be helpful, so we can see the issue. Also: have you disabled all Plugins?

Comment: Please follow your old questions. Comment, make progress. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to **Dashboard -> Appearance -> Menus** and re-applying your custom menus to the appropriate Theme locations.

By changing the directory name, you've impacted the `theme_mods`, including custom menus. To WordPress, **`/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/style.css`** and **`/wp-content/themes/X/style.css`** are two different Themes, *even if all the files are the same*.

Comment: this was exactly the problem, thanks! Also, to get rid of the sitemap in the footer I went into footer.php and deleted: 

    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location'=> 'footer2' ) ); ?>

not sure why it wasn't doing anything BEFORE I changed the folder name, or I would have changed it sooner. but, it's fixed now!

Comment: @jamie If this answer fixed your problem: tick the green checkmark  ✔ on the left side. Do the same on your other questions that are solved by answers. That’s an easy way to make people happy. :)